# Connecting with server linux ubuntu system in Django

Tags: linux, django, django-admin

I have created a sample Django admin page which will do some basic insert update in my local machine.

Now I have installed Django 1.7.7 and python 2.7 in Linux Ubuntu server machine and it has firefox installed.

Is it possible, to connect with the server through any tunnel, so that from my system by `python manage.py runserver localhost:port`?

So that I can actually connect the server computer and can have the admin console page in server which I can access from my local system.

I know that I can do that by  public IP but I dont know the server public ip address nor the domain name.
So any solution for this

Answer (score 0):

The development server listens to `127.0.0.1` by default. In order to connect to your development server from another machine, you need to listen to all IP addresses. Try running the development server by

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

and connect to it from your other PC using:

```
http://server_ip_address:8000
```

Comment: Thanks,but actually i dnt know the Domain name or the public ip of the server linux ubuntu machine...so how can i connect from my PC..... So is there any way with which i can access the web browser of the server from local machine

Comment: Please help me out in this

Comment: @Deb You can find out your server ip by typing `ifconfig` on the Linux console.